# Any way to extract string within 2 different special characters using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I have a varying URL similar to: 
`http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3877/[image_id]_[secret].jpg`

e.g. `http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3877/14628998490_233a15c423_q.jpg`

I need to extract `image_id` that's first set of numbers (i.e. **`14628998490`**) before an underscore from `14628998490_233a15c423_q.jpg` between the whole URL

Is there a good way to extract `image_id`?

Right now I am going to use:

```
var image_id = image_url.match(/[\/]([0-9]+)_/)[1]
```

Comment: You're answering your own question. That regex works, doesn't it?

Comment: you don't need to escape `/` in the character class. you don't need even  a character class also. Just `\/` would be enough.

Comment: @PetervanderWal OP's regex would works only if the part represented by `image_id` contains numbers. It won't works if it contains alphanumeric charcters or anything else.

Comment: @AvinashRaj As stated by OP, it is "that's first set of numbers".

Comment: Ya, he means only in this example.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review. Perhaps [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww That was not code review, but I was gathering suggestion for implementing better code.

@AvinashRaj Thank you for your support buddy, but `image_id` contains numbers only

Comment: @Saurabh - Sorry I offended you. You already have your implementation, and you are looking for better ways. I believe that's more appropriate for Code Review.

Comment: Its okay @jww thank you buddy, I'll consider it next time.

Answer (score 3):

Like i said in the comment, you don't need to escape `/` symbol  in the character class. And also  you don't need even a character class also. Just `\/` would be enough. The below regex would  capture one or more numbers which are preceded by `/` symbol and followed by `_` symbol.

```
\/(\d+)_
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vC2yW4/7)

```
> var image_id = image_url.match(/\/(\d+)_/)[1]
undefined
> image_id
'14628998490'
```

**OR**

You could try this also, if you don't want to give `\d+` in your pattern.

```
\/([^/]*?)_
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vC2yW4/8)

```
> var image_id = image_url.match(/\/([^/]*?)_/)[1]
undefined
> image_id
'14628998490'
```

Comment: How is this any different from the OP's original regex?

Comment: He wants to shortdown his regex. Don't need to escape `/` in the char class.

Answer (score 1):

Not shure that it's is better way, but you can do like this:

```
var str = 'http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3877/[image_id]_[secret].jpg';
var image_id = str.split('/').pop().split('.')[0].split('_');
```

Answer (score 1):

If the special character is always the same (`_`), you could first obtain the last part (width substring+lastIndexOf) and then use split() :

```
var url = "http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3877/14628998490_233a15c423_q.jpg";
var splittedUrl = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1).split("_");
var image_id = splittedUrl[0];
console.log(image_id);
```

I've read somewhere that string functions are faster than regexp, so it's an option you might consider.

Answer (score 0):

String splitting is faster tha regex.You can just get the last index of / and string between first occurence of _ after last occurence of /. I think that will be better idea.